# Prove that: $P(A \triangle B)= P(A)+P(B)-2P(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability

What I did was:
$A \triangle B= (A-B) \cup (B-A) $

$A \triangle B= (A \cup B) - (A \cap B)$

$P(A \triangle B)= P(A)+ P(B) -P(A\cap B) -P( A \cap B) $

Comment: And can you see that $-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap B)=-2P(A\cap B)$?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to type the last step. I just wanted to check if the demo is OK.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  Might want to add something along the lines of $(A\Delta B)\cap (A\cap B)=\emptyset$ so $P((A\Delta B)\cup (A\cap B)=P(A\Delta B)+P(A\cap B)$